# Ban from Canada 5 years. Applying for Australia on student visa

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, australia

I applied for skilled migration visa in 2015 and banned from Canada for misrepresentation. The thing is I honestly lied in the application. 
Now I am applying for student visa in Australia.

Now my question is how to answer this question?

> Disclose any previous visa refusals or cancellations you have received from any country, including Australia and 
>   describe how you addressed the issues identified that resulted in your visa refusals or cancellations.

It says "describe how you address the issues identified that......etc" what should I write here. Should I say that I really lied before when I was applying to Canada?
This time I am applying all genuinely. please help.

Comment: Be creative in explaining the situation. You could get an attorney to advise you on how to craft an answer that reveals nothing but is not untruthful.

Comment: It's hard for me to consult a lawyer at this point. The complication is, I really lie about my job last time when I was applying to Canada. 
So I really don't know to reply this question without telling the truth. "how you addresss...etc" 
i think i should say "last time when i was applying i was not honest about my job" something like that...

Comment: You answer it by telling the truth. We can't give you any advice other than that.

Comment: What was the lie you told?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see what else you can write except that a) you lied about whatever it was; b) why you lied; and, maybe, c) what has changed in your life since then such that you may now be perceived as telling the truth.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) 
well, I lied about my job last time. And still, the ban period is not over. I have no idea how to answer this question.:\
I want to tell the truth. I guess I will write simply what happened.